# What do you think is the error in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, sentence

Identifying Errors:

Two issues in particular (1) graft and corruption and poor quality of public service (2) need the attention of the government (3) to understand it fully and provide the solution to it. (4) NO ERROR (5)

I saw this post on an English grammar facebook group,and members of the group guessed the answer with no explanation. If I were to answer this specific grammar test,I would choose (1) Two issues in particular because, I think, there must be a comma after "in particular." Based on my reading,"in particular" at the beginning of a sentence must always be followed by a comma. Is that correct?

Comment: I'd say there are multiple errors. << Two issues in particular – graft and corruption, and the poor quality of public service – need the attention of the government, which needs to understand the situation fully and provide the solution to it. >>

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things wrong with the sentence.

First, you are correct that there should be a comma after *particular*, and there should also be a comma after *service*.

Second, the word *it* appears twice in part (4); *it* should be replaced by *them*, because *it* refers to *two issues*, which is plural.

Comment: Also: the sentence says "two issues" before listing three issues. "Graft and corruption" may be intended to serve as a single unit but it doesn't really work grammatically.

Comment: @alphabet: Treating "graft and corruption" as a single unit would be perfectly fine grammatically. See [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=graft+and+corruption+is%2Cgraft+and+corruption+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=5). And in fact, that's why there are two "and"s in the sentence — *graft and corruption and poor quality of public service.*